# Firebase Storage emulator does not work with Android

Tags: android, firebase-storage, firebase-tools

I'm running a Firebase emulator on my dev box and setting my clients to connect to the emulator. The setup is pretty straight-forward:

```
storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
storage.useEmulator("192.168.1.214", 9199);
```

And it works fine on iOS. But it doesn't work on Android. The upload is stuck and eventually times out. I'm getting an "Unable to obtain an upload url" error.

- Both iOS and Android devices are connected to the same LAN as the dev box.
- `adb shell ping 192.168.1.214` succeeds, indicating that the dev box is reachable from the Android device.
- Android works fine with the real Firebase instance, just not the emulator.
- iOS works fine with both.
- There's no authentication. The storage is open to all:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using `firebase-bom` so `firebase-storage` is supposed to be the latest version:

```
implementation(platform("com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.7.0"))
implementation("com.google.firebase:firebase-storage")
```

Am I missing something? Thanks.